# Fetch request iin react native getting null parameters data from server in react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, fetch

I am trying to call from fetch request but I am passing parameters on request is fine but when I checked server-side getting null data I am unable to understand whats exact problem after I research i found that charset=utf-8 need to mention so I did still having the same issue.

```
 const request = {
            videoId: data.videoId,
            comments: data.comments,
            views: parseInt(data.views) + 1,
            likes: data.likes,
            shares: data.shares
        }
        alert(JSON.stringify(request));
        fetch(URL + '/VideosController/updateVideo', {
            method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'content-Type': "application/json; charset=utf-8" // "text/html; charset=UTF-8",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(request),
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((postsJson) => {
                alert('res1 + ' + JSON.stringify(postsJson));
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                alert('Error:', JSON.stringify(error));
            });
```

Comment: Looks, Like your react native code is fine. However there may be a problem on server side. Please double check.

Comment: it is working the same service with the postman and I checked now with javascript also all are working. this code only failing. failing means passing parameters are becomes null